# Teradata Wallet configuration for .NET applications

Tags: teradata

We are on TD 15 version. Can TD Wallet be used in .NET applications? If yes, how should it be configured.

Thanks

Comment: Documentation for Teradata Security Administration indicates that TD Wallet works for CLIv2 and ODBC clients only as of TD 15.10

Comment: Thanks for the response!